# MySQL: Access denied for user 'user'@'IP_ADDRESS' - Remote access allowed for some hosts fails for other hosts

Tags: mysql

**Background:** 
I am able to access a mysql instance from some subnets but not others. At least that is what it appears to be.
Machines on network **10.0.21.xx** are able to connect to the MySQL instance. But from **10.0.7.xx**, I get **"Access denied for user using password"**. Interestingly, MySQL is installed on the same subnet (10.0.7.xx) as the machines that it will not authenticate users from.

Here is the command that I issue.

```
 mysql -u user -h 10.0.7.21 -p
```

And the error I get is

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'10.0.7.30' (using password: YES)
```

I have already checked the ***/etc/mysql/my.cnf*** file and made sure that mysqld listens from all IP addresses. I have also checked grant privileges to make sure it is not tied to specific ip addresses.

I'd appreciate if someone can give me additional insight. If you need me to add extra information kindly let me know.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: So check the User account you are using. Is it setup to allow access from `10.0.7.x`

Comment: Remember a MySQL user account has a domain it is allowed to login from so `CREATE USER 'finley'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';` can only login from `localhost` So try amending the acount to something like `CREATE USER 'finley'@'10.0.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';`

Comment: Also ___confused___ You said MYSQL was installed on `10.0.7.xx` but you are connecting to a MySQL Server on `10.0.6.21` when you use `mysql -u user -h 10.0.6.21 -p`

Comment: I have made a correction to the IP address in the command. It should be 10.0.7.21. In the MySQL.user table the host is set to '%' so it should accept from all hosts.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out it was a DNS issue. What led me to go this route is the [MySQL Documenation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-connecting.html):

> If you specify a host name when trying to connect, but get an error message where the host name **is not shown** or **is an IP address**, it means that the MySQL server got an error when trying to resolve the IP address of the client host to a name:

One of the solutions it offers is to flush the DNS host cache; in my case I didn't have this table.

Here are recommended fixes from the documentation:

> Some permanent solutions are:
>
> - Determine what is wrong with your DNS server and fix it.
> - Specify IP addresses rather than host names in the MySQL grant tables.
> - Put an entry for the client machine name in /etc/hosts on Unix or
>     \windows\hosts on Windows.
> - Start mysqld with the --skip-name-resolve option.
> - Start mysqld with the --skip-host-cache option.

In my case I added the IP address of our local DNS server to the client's /etc/resolv.cnf file and then restarted network services (service networking restart).

Answer (score 0):

Get the hostname from your error message and add that to your remote sql host access list.

if you error message is `Access denied for user 'user'@'10.0.7.30' (using password: YES)` then the host name is `10.0.7.30`.

Add it to your remote host access list and you should be connected.